# Adding a dictionary to another

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Merging dictionaries in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294138/merging-dictionaries-in-c)
>   [What's the fastest way to copy the values and keys from one dictionary into another in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81552/whats-the-fastest-way-to-copy-the-values-and-keys-from-one-dictionary-into-anoth)

I have a dictionary that has some values in it, say:

```
Animals <string, string>
```

I now receive another similar dictionary, say:

```
NewAnimals <string,string>
```

How can I append the entire NewAnimals dictionary to Animals?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

```
foreach(var newAnimal in NewAnimals)
    Animals.Add(newAnimal.Key,newAnimal.Value)
```

Note: this throws an exception on a duplicate key.

---

Or if you really want to go the extension method route(I wouldn't), then you could define a general `AddRange` extension method that works on any `ICollection<T>`, and not just on `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`.

```
public static void AddRange<T>(this ICollection<T> target, IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    if(target==null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(target));
    if(source==null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    foreach(var element in source)
        target.Add(element);
}
```

(throws on duplicate keys for dictionaries)

Comment: No problem. Duplicate keys are not a worry.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at my solution and implement `AddRange`. I did all the work for you.

Comment: @gmcalab: I do appreciate it, however this solution works just fine for me and is a lot smaller. I was really looking for something tiny that does the job.

Comment: what kind of exception does it throw? just a plain Exception?

Comment: @Mahan MSDN for the [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.Add` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7z0zy8k.aspx) says `ArgumentException` - An element with the same key already exists in the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`.

Comment: Why don't we do this to avoid ArguementException? `foreach ( var property in anotherProperties ) properties[property.Key] = property.Value;`

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to write an extention method?

Answer (score 44):

Create an **Extension Method** most likely you will want to use this more than once and this prevents duplicate code.

**Implementation:**

```
 public static void AddRange<T, S>(this Dictionary<T, S> source, Dictionary<T, S> collection)
 {
        if (collection == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Collection is null");
        }

        foreach (var item in collection)
        {
            if(!source.ContainsKey(item.Key)){ 
               source.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
            }
            else
            {
               // handle duplicate key issue here
            }  
        } 
 }
```

**Usage:**

```
Dictionary<string,string> animals = new Dictionary<string,string>();
Dictionary<string,string> newanimals = new Dictionary<string,string>();

animals.AddRange(newanimals);
```

Comment: Why don't you type the right parameter as `IEnumerable<KeyValue<TKey,TValue>>`? And why do you use only one generic parameter for key and value?

Comment: @CodesInChaos, what the point to have second argument as  IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>?  Particular use cases?

Comment: I added
public enum OnDuplicateKey
    {
        Throw,
        Skip,
       Replace
    }

Comment: @vkelman 1) It's satisfied by any dictionary 2) I sometimes produce sequences via Linq that I then want to add to a dictionary.

Answer (score 13):

The most obvious way is:

```
foreach(var kvp in NewAnimals)
   Animals.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value); 
  //use Animals[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value instead if duplicate keys are an issue
```

Since `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`explicitly implements the`ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Add`method, you can also do this:

```
var animalsAsCollection = (ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, string>>) Animals;

foreach(var kvp in NewAnimals)
   animalsAsCollection.Add(kvp);
```

It's a pity the class doesn't have an`AddRange`method like`List<T>` does.

Comment: agreed. AddRange is convenient.

Comment: That's why you write an extension method, which is the best solution to this question but not chosen by the OP. Spaghetti code ahoy!

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is, you have to loop.

More info on this topic:

[What's the fastest way to copy the values and keys from one dictionary into another in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81552/whats-the-fastest-way-to-copy-the-values-and-keys-from-one-dictionary-into-anoth)

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through all the Animals using foreach and put it into NewAnimals.